# How do I use Varchar(max) output from a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure in an old ASP/VBScript app?

Tags: sql-server-2008, vbscript, asp-classic, varcharmax

Here's the sproc:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[cms_createNoteMultipleRecID] (
  @NoteDt smalldatetime, 
  ...
  @NoteIDCSV VARCHAR(max) OUTPUT
)
```

And here's the VBScript:

```
cmd.CommandText = "cms_createNoteMultipleRecID"
cmd.Parameters.Append = cmd.CreateParameter("@RC", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
cmd.Parameters.Append = cmd.CreateParameter("@NoteDt", adDBDate, adParamInput,, NoteDt )
...
cmd.Parameters.Append = cmd.CreateParameter("@NoteIDCSV", adLongVarWChar, adParamOutput )
```

Seems like adLongVarWChar works for input, as I have used it a few times. But, what's the proper way to use a varchar(max) output in VBScript? As-is, my error states: "Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided." from ADODB.

Comment: SQL Server does not support the adDBDate datatype. You have to correct this problem, change the datatype of the @NoteDt parameter to adDBTimeStamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append = cmd.CreateParameter("@NoteIDCSV", adBStr, adParamOutput, -1 )
```

Open to better ideas.

Answer (score 2):

set the size argument to `CreateParameter` to `-1`. I think this is the syntax (can't test at the moment):

```
cmd.Parameters.Append = cmd.CreateParameter("@NoteIDCSV", adLongVarWChar, adParamOutput, -1 )
```